# unlogical ascii character redirect - HTACCESS

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

Is there any way of making a `301 redirect` from:

```
/@done
```

to

```
/bin
```

I currently have this code situated in my `.htaccess` file:

```
Redirect 301 /@done /bin
```

But it does not redirect because of the illogical placement of the `@`, within the statement, is there any way to overcome this? With the resulting URL still redirecting from the address of `example.com/@done`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `@` character is a reserved character in URLs according to [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2).
You could try whether it helps to use the character's encoded representation `%40` instead.

---

**Update**
You could create the folder `@done` at the proper place of the webserver and put an `index.php` file in it. This will redirect all requests from `/@done` to `/bin`.

```
<?php
    header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header("Location: /bin"); 
    header("Connection: close");           
?>
```

Comment: Maybe you could try to solve this problem without using .htaccess. I've added an alternative approach with the help of php. Could this be helpful for you?